# column indexing and sql profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have enabled sql profiler and identified several queries that are taking a long time to execute.

For example:

```
Select A from table_A where B = 2
```

My question is, based on above query, do I create indexes on column A or B? or A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index on `B` including column `A`. The where can use a seek on `B` while still returning `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Your index should be on B since that's what is in your condition. You might benefit from just trying out all the ways and looking at the resulting [execution plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would create an index on column B because that is what sql server is doing the comparison on.  Afterwards I would run the profiler again to see if adding the index negatively impacts other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate indexes on B and A. Creating index on A is to avoid KEY LOOKUP.